# How to debug "INVALID_ARGUMENT: input tensor alias not found in signature"

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to access my tensorflow serving model which has a signature as can be seen from this code segment:

```
regression_signature = predict_signature_def(
    inputs={"phase_features" : phase_features},
    outputs={"phase_weight": phase_weight}
)

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess=sess, 
    tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={'regress_phase_weight': regression_signature})
builder.save()
```

It is loaded in tf serving using a model config file with the following content:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "PhaseModificationWeightRegressor",
    base_path: "../../models/phase-mod-weights",
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a request from Java based on the TensorFlow API and TensorFlow Serving API protos:

```
...
tensorflow.serving.Model.ModelSpec.Builder modelSped = ModelSpec.newBuilder()
              .setName("PhaseModificationWeightRegressor") // name as defined in the tensorflow serving model config file
              .setSignatureName("regress_phase_weight") // signature name as defined in signature_def_map of add_meta_graph_and_variables of your SavedModelBuilder
              .setVersion(Int64Value.newBuilder().setValue(1)); // model version as indicated by the version of your model when saving it

tensorflow.serving.Predict.PredictRequest.Builder requestBuilder = PredictRequest.newBuilder()
              .setModelSpec(modelSped)
              .putInputs("phase_features", createTensorProto(phaseFeatures));

      return requestBuilder.build();
```

Unfortunately I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: input tensor alias not found in signature: phase_features
```

From what I understand, this means it reached the server, FOUND my model named "PhaseModificationWeightRegressor" in version 1, FOUND the signature named "regress_phase_weight", but could not find the logical name (alias) "phase_features" which leads to the appropriate placeholder. Anything else that could be the problem? I am eye-balling this now since 2 hours but can not see the problem/typo etc. that makes this not work.

Any idea what could be wrong? How can I debug this any better? Maybe in the future, TFserving should answer what it expects instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with:

```
‍.putInputs("inputs", createTensorProto(phaseFeatures));
```

It seems to that the alias to be used from the client is exactly `"inputs"`, while the python code remains the same.
With this modification my code works.

**UPDATE**: I tested it also with a model with multiple (two) inputs. In this case, you should use the alias you are using while exporting the model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will test this as soon as possible. Then I will accept your answer or maybe ask for more help!

Comment: That is exactly the problem. So if you use only one input, just have to use "inputs" and for two or more inputs, you have to use the aliases? That sounds weird to me, can you confirm that to be correct on your side?

Comment: Yeah, i did it in this way. It sounded weird to me too, but it works (apparently)

Comment: @EricMcLachlan: You are right. Just accepted the only answer, even though at the time it did not help me as far as I remember.